# JPA JoinColumn Annotation

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

In my JPA class, I have this Annotation and the syntax I am not able to understand

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="RES_ID", referencedColumnName="ACCT_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="DELETED", referencedColumnName="'N'")
})
protected Account account;
```

The first line is ok: The current class has column in db (`RES_ID`) which joins with `Account` which has a column `ACCT_ID`

But the second line says :

```
@JoinColumn(name="DELETED", referencedColumnName="'N'")
```

Now both these tables have a column called `DELETED`. Is that a shorthand  way of saying that join the two tables when both these tables have `DELETED = 'N'`?

Because the documentation says that `referencedColumn` should contain a `columnName`. here it is containing a `value = N`

Comment: Nowhere in the specification does it mention that `referencedColumnName` can contain a discriminator value to join on. Does this code actually work?

Comment: 'N' is not really a discriminator value. Because the DELETED is not marked as a discriminatorcolumn. But the code works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, you're using OpenJPA? This is surely not a specified JPA feature, but OpenJPA has such a feature called *constant joins* in its [Non-Standard Joins](http://openjpa.apache.org/docs/latest/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html).